# JSF init not called on page refresh

Tags: jsf

I have jsf session scoped bean. Its init method having annotation @PostConstruct is called when the page is loaded for the first time but not on every reload or refresh. I want to call some method on every page refresh. What annotation or change in xhtml file do I need to use

Comment: Which annotation are you using? If you’re using a `@ViewScope` annotation it will be loaded each time the page is loaded. If you are using `@SessionScoped` the data will be persisted through all the users session.

Comment: I am using session scope, and I want method to be called for each refresh

Comment: Just change it to ViewScope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Answer (score 1):

Try change your annotation tag as follows

Just change it to ViewScope. import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class YourControllerClass implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method on every page refresh it 's better to use **ComponentSystemEvent**.

You can refer below link
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_applicationevents_tag.htm